# Firebase dynamic link ios error after changing appID to use teamID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I implemented firebase dynamic link, before changing the AppID to use TeamID everything works fine, but after that, the dynamic link become not working anymore. I just check AAPS the format and even the `appID` value has the same value with TeamID.

Here is what I got

```
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ----
Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 4.2.0
System information: OS iOS, OS version 15.2.1, model iPhone
Current date 2022-02-04 03:04:09 +0000
Device locale en-ID (raw en_ID), timezone Asia/Jakarta
    Specified custom URL scheme is com.xxx.xxxx and Info.plist contains such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.
    AppID Prefix: AAAAAA, Team ID: BBBBBB, AppId Prefix equal to Team ID: NO
performDiagnostic completed successfully! No errors found.
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end ----
```

But when I try these config in simulator, everything works fine.

I just wasted 2 days trying to solve the issue but no luck. Any body here could help me solve the issue?